# How to find the free memory addresses in RAM?

Tags: memory-management

I am currently trying to build a simple computer in Minecraft (8-bit data, 6-bit addresses, no paging or segmentation), with redstone, where I can make run simple programs written similarly to code in the Little Man Computer. However, I have come across the problem that I have no idea which addresses in RAM are free to use.

I have seen Linux, for example, has an array that describes each address (that I am guessing includes if it is free or not). In my case, however, it seems impractical to create a massive block of memory dedicated to this, that will be a very similar size to even the RAM itself, due to having the same length for addresses.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is there a more efficient method than creating a large block of storage? Is there a way to decrease the size of the storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory allocator is typically responsible for keeping track of which areas in memory are free.  For instance, the memory allocator might keep a list of which regions of memory are free and available for allocation.  This is called, appropriately, the "free list".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management.

Comment: Thanks!!! this helped a lot.